# A question about a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Somebody can to help me with a hint in the following question?

> Let $G$ be a group and for any $x,y\in G$, consider the element $z\in G$ given by
>   $$ z = [x,y]:= x^{-1} y^{-1} x y.$$
>   Let $H$ be the subgroup $H := \langle\; z=[x,y]\; |\; x,y \in G \;\rangle$. Show that $H\lhd G$.

Comment: The $H$ you have defined there is the [commutator subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) of $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct argument: If $c \in H$ and $g \in G$ then $gcg^{-1}c^{-1}$ is in $H$, and hence so is $(gcg^{-1}c^{-1})c = gcg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\forall g\in G,\ gzg^{-1}=gx^{-1}y^{-1}xyg^{-1}=gx^{-1}\color{red}{g^{-1}g}y^{-1}\color{red}{{g}^{-1}g}x\color{red}{g^{-1}g}yg^{-1}=(gxg^{-1})^{-1}(gyg^{-1})^{-1}(gxg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})=[gxg^{-1},gyg^{-1}]\in H$$

Comment: Colored one is more preferable. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $g \in G$ and consider

$$[gxg^{-1}, gyg^{-1}] = (gxg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})(gx^{-1}g^{-1})(gy^{-1}g^{-1}) = g [x, y]g^{-1}$$